# How to append a new row in a dataframe by searching for an existing column value without iterating?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, row

I'm trying to find the best way to create new rows for every 1 row when a certain value is contained in a column.

Example Dataframe

| Index | Person | Drink_Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | Jack and Coke |
| 2 | John | Coke |
| 3 | Steve | Dr. Pepper |

I'd like to search the DataFrame for Jack and Coke, remove it and add 2 new records as Jack and Coke are 2 different drink sources.

| Index | Person | Drink_Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | John | Coke |
| 3 | Steve | Dr. Pepper |
| 4 | Sam | Jack Daniels |
| 5 | Sam | Coke |

Example Code that I want to replace as my understanding is you should never modify rows you are iterating

```
for index, row in df.loc[df['Drink_Order'].str.contains('Jack and Coke')].iterrows():
    df.loc[len(df)]=[row['Person'],'Jack Daniels']
    df.loc[len(df)]=[row['Person'],'Coke']

df = df[df['Drink_Order']!= 'Jack and Coke']
```

Answer (score 1):

Split using and. That will result in a list. Explode list to get each element in a list appear as an individual row. Then conditionally rename Jack to Jack Daniels

```
 df= df.assign(Drink_Order=df['Drink_Order'].str.split('and')).explode('Drink_Order')
df['Drink_Order']=np.where(df['Drink_Order'].str.contains('Jack'),'Jack Daniels',df['Drink_Order'])

    Index Person   Drink_Order
0      1    Sam  Jack Daniels
0      1    Sam          Coke
1      2   John          Coke
2      3  Steve    Dr. Pepper
```

Comment: Was this helpful?

Comment: Is it, but what if I didnt want to split using and and explode? What if I wanted to add "ice" as a line item?

Comment: What do you mean. Add sample output please

Comment: The same ouput with 1 additional row 4 | Sam | Ice